# Clouldwatch client of boto3 module

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, datetime, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

```
import boto3
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import datetime

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    region = 'us-east-1'
    cwWindow = 60
    cloudwatch = boto3.client('cloudwatch', region_name='us-east-1')

# List metrics through the pagination interface
    response = cloudwatch.get_metric_statistics(
    Namespace='AWS/EC2',
    MetricName='CPUUtilization',
    Dimensions=[
        {
            'Name': 'InstanceId',
            'Value': 'i-09deabee19c5fc46d'
        },
    ],
    StartTime=datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(minutes = 60),
    EndTime=datetime.utcnow(),
    Period=300,
    Statistics=['Average', 'Maximum'],
    Unit='Percent'
)

    return response
```

we have written function to get the CPUUtilization metric of my ec2 instance but I am getting below error "datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 11, 12, 3, tzinfo=tzlocal()) is not JSON serializable
":

```
Response
{
    "errorType": "TypeError",
    "errorMessage": "datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 11, 12, 3, tzinfo=tzlocal()) is not JSON serializable",
    "stackTrace": [
        "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py\", line 238, in dumps\n    **kw).encode(obj)\n",
        "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py\", line 199, in encode\n    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)\n",
        "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py\", line 257, in iterencode\n    return _iterencode(o, 0)\n",
        "  File \"/var/runtime/awslambda/bootstrap.py\", line 149, in decimal_serializer\n    raise TypeError(repr(o) + \" is not JSON serializable\")\n"
    ]
}

Function Logs
An error occurred during JSON serialization of response: datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 11, 12, 3, tzinfo=tzlocal()) is not JSON serializable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/var/runtime/awslambda/bootstrap.py", line 149, in decimal_serializer
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 11, 12, 3, tzinfo=tzlocal()) is not JSON serializable

Request ID
057aa5a4-74f6-1881-a024-74f6c2134125
```

We are using same format as told in the boto3 documentation but, still getting error. If anyone have experience in cloudwatch client of boto3. Need help.

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue. What python version do you use?

Comment: I am using python 3.6. have you ever used cloudwatch client of boto3 module?

Comment: yes. But now I just checked your code with my instance. Don't see an issue.

Comment: Does it provide datapoints? Can you post your code and response? Which IDE you are using? I am trying using cloud9.

Comment: yes. This is an example output: https://pastebin.com/raw/DsQv6eJ0

Comment: The above link is not reachable.

Comment: I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet works. I just changed it to my instance id. Example output is below.

```
{
   "Label":"CPUUtilization",
   "Datapoints":[
      {
         "Timestamp":datetime.datetime(2020,
         3,
         12,
         6,
         2,
         "tzinfo=tzutc())",
         "Average":0.06612021857923481,
         "Maximum":0.166666666666666,
         "Unit":"Percent"
      },
      {
         "Timestamp":datetime.datetime(2020,
         3,
         12,
         5,
         32,
         "tzinfo=tzutc())",
         "Average":0.112052730696798,
         "Maximum":0.169491525423728,
         "Unit":"Percent"
      },
      {
         "Timestamp":datetime.datetime(2020,
         3,
         12,
         6,
         7,
         "tzinfo=tzutc())",
         "Average":0.0672316384180794,
         "Maximum":0.169491525423731,
         "Unit":"Percent"
      },
      {
         "Timestamp":datetime.datetime(2020,
         3,
         12,
         5,
         37,
         "tzinfo=tzutc())",
         "Average":0.06668519033064779,
         "Maximum":0.169491525423728,
         "Unit":"Percent"
      },
      {
         "Timestamp":datetime.datetime(2020,
         3,
         12,
         6,
         12,
         "tzinfo=tzutc())",
         "Average":0.06559139784946219,
         "Maximum":0.166666666666666,
         "Unit":"Percent"
      },
      {
         "Timestamp":datetime.datetime(2020,
         3,
         12,
         5,
         42,
         "tzinfo=tzutc())",
         "Average":0.06612021857923481,
         "Maximum":0.166666666666666,
         "Unit":"Percent"
      },
      {
         "Timestamp":datetime.datetime(2020,
         3,
         12,
         5,
         47,
         "tzinfo=tzutc())",
         "Average":0.09890710382513698,
         "Maximum":0.166666666666666,
         "Unit":"Percent"
      },
      {
         "Timestamp":datetime.datetime(2020,
         3,
         12,
         5,
         52,
         "tzinfo=tzutc())",
         "Average":0.0344827586206896,
         "Maximum":0.172413793103448,
         "Unit":"Percent"
      },
      {
         "Timestamp":datetime.datetime(2020,
         3,
         12,
         5,
         57,
         "tzinfo=tzutc())",
         "Average":0.1328054089098826,
         "Maximum":0.169491525423728,
         "Unit":"Percent"
      }
   ],
   "ResponseMetadata":{
      "RequestId":"f69967e9-be32-49eb-8442-f06000e7e842",
      "HTTPStatusCode":200,
      "HTTPHeaders":{
         "x-amzn-requestid":"f69967e9-be32-49eb-8442-f06000e7e842",
         "content-type":"text/xml",
         "content-length":"2185",
         "vary":"accept-encoding",
         "date":"Thu, 12 Mar 2020 06:19:39 GMT"
      },
      "RetryAttempts":0
   }
}
```

My code:

```
import boto3
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import datetime

dev = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='la')

cloudwatch = dev.client('cloudwatch', region_name='us-east-1')


response = cloudwatch.get_metric_statistics(
    Namespace='AWS/EC2',
    MetricName='CPUUtilization',
    Dimensions=[
        {
            'Name': 'InstanceId',
            'Value': 'i-0b2762b6610c73e02'
        },
    ],
    StartTime=datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(minutes = 60),
    EndTime=datetime.utcnow(),
    Period=300,
    Statistics=['Average', 'Maximum'],
    Unit='Percent'
)

print(response)
```

Comment: Can you post the code? Because I am not getting the output for the above code that I am using.

Comment: @papali I added the code. I needed to use customize session for myself, but call to `get_metric_statistics` is same.

Comment: Is it because I am using my Office network to access my Lambda functions? Why have you used customize session for yourself?

Comment: @papali I don't know, but your call to `get_metric_statistics` is correct. Something else must be happening.

Comment: whenever I am giving the timedelta(minute = 2) then, the datapoint come []. but, if giving timedelta(minute = 60) the above error is throwing.

Comment: ```{
  "Label": "CPUUtilization",
  "Datapoints": [],
  "ResponseMetadata": {
    "RequestId": "b0f95ce0-8701-4c26-8f75-a9fb1216fd18",
    "HTTPStatusCode": 200,
    "HTTPHeaders": {
      "x-amzn-requestid": "b0f95ce0-8701-4c26-8f75-a9fb1216fd18",
      "content-type": "text/xml",
      "content-length": "337",
      "date": "Thu, 12 Mar 2020 17:21:02 GMT"
    },
    "RetryAttempts": 0
  }
}```This is the output I get when I try on my own laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not in your boto code, it's in the fact that you're returning the response from lambda. The response is not serializable.

Why do you need lambda to return the response? Have lambda do what it needs to do and return "OK" or something like that.

Comment: Can you explain what you told? Actually we want to build a dashboard application which will have:- Monthly trend (upto 1 year) of cost by cost center.Monthly trend (upto 1 year) of cost by usage type – EC2, S3, RDS, etc. There are usually around 20+ types of usage.Consumption till date in current month by cost center, by usage type. Projected current month usage at same rate. Compare that with previous month value. Ability to drill down to server level information.

Comment: Maybe look into GetMetricWidgetImage API. You can get the graph directly from CloudWatch instead of getting the data and graphing is yourself.